# For some reason named route is not working in Functional Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, functional-testing

Inside of my Quizzes Controller functional test :

```
post :statements
```

Returns ->

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"quizzes", :action=>"statements"}
```

But my routes rake as so :

```
quizzes_statements  /quizzes/statements(.:format)  quizzes#statements {:any=>[:OPTIONS, :POST]}
```

My routes.rb looks like so :

```
match '/quizzes/statements' => 'quizzes#statements', any: [:OPTIONS, :POST]
```

And if I run this within my test :

```
extend Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
quizzes_statements_path
```

Returns :

```
=> "/quizzes/statements"
```

But if I do :

```
post quizzes_statements_path
```

I get the same error :

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"quizzes", :action=>"/quizzes/statements"}
```

Anyone know what might be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
match '/quizzes/statements' => 'quizzes#statements', via: [:options, :post]
```

Comment: That was brilliant @Kirti Thorat . Thank you very much. ॐ

Answer (score 0):

In controller(functional) tests you can only reach actions within this controller, expressed by symbol.

e.g.

```
post :statements
get :index
```

Note `get`, `post` in functional tests are totally different methods from what in integration tests, though they have same name. You can use named path in integration tests without any problem. e.g.

```
post statement_path
```

So the fix is, do not used named path in your functional tests. get/post to action directly.